# How to extract color from color.new()

Tags: pine-script

```
orangeWith80Transp = color.new(color.orange, 80)
```

How do I extract the color without transparency from `orangeWith80Transp`?

```
pureOrange = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pureOrange = color.new(color.orange, 0)
```

or

```
pureOrange = color.new(orangeWith80Transp, 0)
```

Comment: The second one was what I was looking for. Thank you.